# React component breaks? I cannot figure out why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component gets array of objects from server and sets it in `this.state` object.
But at rendering moment (`this.state` is updated with `this.setState()` due to fetch method at the moment `componentWillMount(){}`) I cannot get normally operate with inside-state array. Why? It outputs me that array is undefined inside `render(){}` function, and I cannot get `recipes.length` of array also.

There is a code of Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Router, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router';
import '../css/Recipes.css';
import EditRecipe from '../js/EditRecipe';
import DeleteRecipe from '../js/DeleteRecipe';
import CreateProposal from '../js/CreateProposal';
import CreateRecipe from "./CreateRecipe";

class Recipes extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            recipes: [] 
        };
        this.renderRec = this.renderRec.bind(this);
        this.getRec = this.getRec.bind(this);
    }
    renderRec(recipe){
        return <div key={recipe.id}>{recipe.name}</div>
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.getRec();
    }
    getRec(_){
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/recipes')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({recipes: data});
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    render() {
        const recipes = this.state.recipes;
        const howManyRecipes = recipes.length;
        console.log(recipes.data.length);
        const view = howManyRecipes > 0 ? <Route component={this.state.recipes.map(this.renderRec)} /> : <Route component={CreateProposal}/>;
        console.log(view);
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Our community did {howManyRecipes} recipes</div>
                {view}
            </div>     
        );
    }
}

export default Recipes;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: console.log(recipes.data.length); should be   console.log(recipes.length); to log the proper information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `componentWillMount` lifecycle hook for asynchronous operations. Use `componenDidMount` instead.

The actual problem that your request can took too long so it won't be set at initial render thus your array will stay empty as in the initial state.

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

See more in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Answer (score 1):

Problem comes from

```
console.log(recipes.data.length);
```

before the componentWillMount renders you have :

```
 recipes = this.state.recipes = []
```

Therefore recipes.data is undefined and can not get the length value.

Either remove the line or change the line to (e.g.) :

```
console.log(recipes.data ? recipes.data.length : recipes.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, You should avoid making api call in `componentWillMount` move this to `componentDidMount` instead.

Second,

`recipes.data` is not always defined. It will always be defined once you have done successful api call.